# Not all options listed in voting to close

Tags: support, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I would like to understand why when the system asks me to close a question I have only three options and the other options are not visible. For example it is not viewable: the question is resolved in the comments or other possibilities that I see from the closure of other users and not when I decide to close a question on my screen.

[image]

Comment: Can you point to "other possibilities that I see from the closure of other users"?

Comment: @Werner Yes of course. You can see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430225/cannot-create-a-bibliography-section-for-my-phd-proposal: the user gusbrs can have this option: **I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reasons you note that is absent in the choices for voting to close a question as off-topic stems from the original close-voter using the "Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)" choice and writing an appropriate comment.

You'll note that there is no mention within the closure notification added to a question other than it's off-topic. Consider [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430225/5764) that was closed as off-topic via the "Other ..." method:

[image]

The comment added by the original close-voter is added to the list of comments below the question in order to notify the original author:

[image]

Once the "Other ..." closure option is chosen and a comment is added, it's added as one of the reasons within the closure dialog for future visitors that have the [vote-to-close privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). The upvotes accompanying the closure-comment gives an indication of the number of users that chose that exact same reason to close the question.

<sub>The suggested comment for closure is prefixed with "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because" so as to make sense within the voting structure. However, you could add whatever detail you want as a comment.</sub>

Comment: +1 for your excellent answer and check V. Thank you always.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that whilst people have put 'answered in comments', that's not in itself a reason: it's more that the question isn't going to have a clear answer, usually (something entirely localised to the OP or similar).